# this permision (android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) was automatically added to Manifest

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app that it worked well until upgrade packages Actually after upgrade packages this permision added (android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) to manifest.please help me

this is first package.json

```
  {
  "name": "mazeapp",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gregfrench/react-native-wheel-picker": "^1.2.15",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "6.7.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.4",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "3.2.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.6.5",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-emoji": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-file-picker": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.6",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.4",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-item-select": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-motion": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-persian-calendar-picker": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "0.18.3",
    "react-native-progress": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "0.8.1",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "0.11.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.7.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "2.10.1",
    "react-number-format": "4.4.1",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "styled-components": "5.2.1",
    "victory-native": "^33.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "jetifier": "1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-native-bundle-visualizer": "2.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

this is secound file package.json

```
 {
  "name": "mazeapp",
  "version": "2.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-background-actions": "^2.6.4",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.6.5",
    "react-native-emoji": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-file-picker": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.4",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-item-select": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-motion": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-persian-calendar-picker": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-select-contact": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "0.11.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-number-format": "4.4.1",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "victory-native": "^33.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-bundle-visualizer": "2.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // googlePlayServicesVersion = "4.3.3" // default: "+"
        // firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because of target SDK updated to 30, some features (eg: Speech recognition,TTS) works in from android 11 device only after adding following code in our AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:node="remove" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

also `android:exported="true"` inside `<activity>`

It is mentioned in here [Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#change-details)

You might have to exclusively declare the tools namespace in the manifest header tag for this to work. `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` so that the header will look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">
```

Comment: I added it but it did not work

Comment: i add this code and works  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"
      tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

Comment: Great!, Updated that in answer.

Comment: Still does not work for me.

Answer (score 16):

For those having a similar issue or that have to explain to the Play Store why this permission is in place, this is added by react-native-inappbrowser-reborn package, there is a PR to fix that here:

https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/pull/335

It seems that at the time writing this post, it's not live in the NPM directory. But you should try to update the package and see if its gone.

One way to figure out which dependency injects permissions is by running this command at the root of your project (on unix based OS):

```
grep -r QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES *
```

This will tell you the file that has that text and this will point you on the right direction.

Comment: I get things like this `android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /> <!-- Create a unique permission for your app and use it so only your app can receive your OneSignal messages. -->` what does that mean ?

Comment: @Hugo Did you ever figure out why OneSignal was creating QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES? I keep getting this and Google keeps rejecting my app due to it

Comment: Indeed I don't think the issue was coming from onesignal but rather from the @react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

Comment: This is working for me for searching the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can confirm that the package is included in your apk using.

[apkTook](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

1. install using instructions on website
2. build your apk
3. run `apktool decode /path/to/your/app-release.apk`
4. There should now be a giant merged manifest file containing all permissions for your apk.

Once you have confirmed that the permission is included in your apk.

You can then use @imekinox 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758445/1461176) to detect which dependency is including the permission.

You can then chose to disable the permission from appearing in your final APk file

by including the following change in your manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.cortexmonitoring">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

Notice that `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` is required at the top of the manifest file.

More than likely the issue is https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/pull/335 and disabling the permission in this way may break this or other packages.

The real fix would be removing or updating any dependencies that include this permission.

Answer (score 1):

for the ones who follow @Thanhal's answer:

check your AndroidManifest.xml file and add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to the manifest markup if it's not there.

example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="your-app-package">
```

Answer (score 0):

@imekinox has the correct solution, however, after I went to the Github page he linked, the fix for react-native-inappbrowser is merged but no new release with it has been published yet.

I found another NPM release that has it included:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jinshin1013/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

Uninstall the old version and install this version and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is great probability that your app will get rejected by Play store if you use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

As mentioned in below link "In the rare cases where the  element doesn't provide adequate package visibility, you can use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. If you publish your app on Google Play, your app's use of this permission is subject to approval."

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Add queries to AndroidManifest.xml file as mentioned below.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```